# Can't locate WWW/Mechanize.pm: Using cpanm doesn't work

Tags: macos, bash, perl

I know this is a duplicate, but my question was not answered in any other threads. the output of `sudo cpanm WWW::Mechanize` is to long to put in tread. [pastebin: 3BYUtSss](http://pastebin.com/3BYUtSss)

I tried executing a perl script, and I get this error:

```
Can't locate WWW/Mechanize.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3 /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.3 /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.3 /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl .) at io.pl line 5.
```

In case you need it, here is my perl script's contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

my ($get,$host,$title);
while (<>) {
    if (m|^GET (\S+) |) {
        $get = $1;
    } elsif ( m|^Host: (\S+)\.| ) {
        $host = $1;
    } else {
        # Unrecognized line...reset
        $get = $host = $title = '';
    }

    if ($get and $host) {
        my ($title) = $get =~ m|^.*\/(.+?)$|; # default title
        my $url = 'http://' . $host . $get;
        $mech->get($url);
        if ($mech->success) {
            # HTML may have title, images will not
            $title = $mech->title() || $title;
        }
        print "Title: $title\n";
        print "URL: $url\n";
        print "\n";

        $get = $host = $title = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is your installation of WWW::Mechanize, not your program.  You say "Using cpanm doesn't work", but we have no idea why that is.  Please edit your question to show the results of trying to install WWW::Mechanize.

Comment: The `/opt/local` path indicates MacPorts, so another alternative would be to install the appropriate package, e.g. something like `sudo port install p5-www-mechanize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key lines in the `cpanm` output are:

```
Building and testing CGI-4.21 ... FAIL
! Installing CGI failed. See /Users/skylerspaeth/.cpanm/work/1440436409.90704/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

So look in `/Users/skylerspaeth/.cpanm/work/1440436409.90704/build.log` and see what the problem is.  If that log is no longer there, you may need to run `cpanm` again, which will generate another `build.log`.

You find the key lines in `cpanm` output by searching for "fail".  Usually, it'll point you at a `build.log` file for further details.

Answer (score 3):

These look to be the key lines in the output from cpanm, down at the bottom.

```
! Installing the dependencies failed: Installed version (3.59) of CGI is not in range '4.08'
! Bailing out the installation for WWW-Mechanize-1.75.
```

Looks like you need to install a higher version of the CGI distribution.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Probably the same way you're installing WWW::Mechanize.  Use cpanm.

Comment: What would the name be? WWW::CGI?

Comment: @AndyLester, no, the key lines are where it tried to install CGI 4.21 and failed.  See my answer.